# Chat one to one using asp.net core SignalR and angular 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

[image][image]Here i called the method into my SignalR Hub Class to brodcast messages to user.i did another method for to send messages to all connected users but now i want to sendand receive messages between two user

Comment: One option is to make a group for each new chat partners

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but i didn't found creating group .net core .And if it's not a new Chat the group old group will disappear?

Comment: inside your hub you have: Groups.AddAsync("YourGroupId", Context.ConnectionId); There is also RemoveAsync

Comment: sorry i'm new in the SignalR.What is the Context.ConnectionId ?And in the case of Join group means that the group is created

Comment: Each client which connects to a hub gets unique Id. So you have to add you both chatpartners to a group. Simple add there ConnectionId (which you will get with Conext.ConnectionId) to the group.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation i would like to ask you the "GroupId" from where should i get it or created?

Comment: Create by yourself. Forexample you can use a guid or something like that. I do not know your requirements. Maybe you have methods attendToChatRoom or leaveChatRoom? Or you you plan the "handshake" between you chatpartners?

Comment: I don't have any method like leaveChatRoom ,leaveChatRoom but i need just a method that allows to private chat between users.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

**Create groups**

Add a client to a group:

```
Groups.AddAsync("YourGroupId", Context.ConnectionId);
```

Remove client from group:

```
Groups.RemoveAsync("YourGroupId", Context.ConnectionId);
```

Send message to a group:

```
Clients.Group("").MethodOnYourClient("");
```

Remark:
I suggest you to read the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

I know it's not with asp.net core signalr, but the most of the stuff looks similar. Maybe you have to show in intellisense which possibilities the existing classes have.

Comment: I don't have any method like leaveChatRoom ,leaveChatRoom but i need just a method that allows to private chat between users

Comment: You have to think about the whole system. Take for example skype. First you start. Then other users see that you connected and you see the other connected users. Then you like to click for example on another user and a new "chat-window" opens. There you have to make the group for this two clients. So there is no general magic method. You have to make a sketch snd think about the system of your chat.

Comment: I have successfully send message to a specific client instantly if he's joining the group.But in my case in my interface I have list of discussions and if I click in an item of the list of discussions the all messages between me and the client will be appearing in another interface so i have call the JoinGroup Methode in the hub to let the user join the group.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "in my case in my interface"... maybe somecode will help. I suggest you have an addtional problem, but the intial questions is answered?